# How to target a input box with selenium when the ID changes?

Tags: javascript, selenium, yammer

Trying to automate certain tests dealing with Yammer. What I want to do is to use selenium to post something, but when I click on the textbox it changes it's id. Also, everytime the page reloads, or a post is made, that textbox changes it's id.

So what I did next was to use wildcards by telling selenium to look for

```
//input[starts-with(id, 'yamjs')]
```

However, I quickly found out that yamjs is used for both the body of the update as well as the  "+ Add people to notify" textbox.

The difference between the two seems to be the class. The one that we're interested in has a `class="yj-tapf-textarea"` whereas the add people to notify textbox has a `class="yj-callout-bar-entry-field"`

How do I get selenium to find the input field with the id that starts with yamjs within the class yj-tapf-textarea, and not the one in the class yj-callout-bar-entry-field?

Comment: does the structure of the page (or the form) stays always the same regardless the ids/class names of the inputs?

Comment: No. It looks like the yj-callout-bar-entry-field only appears after you click on yj-tapf-textarea.

Comment: have you tried something like storing what's in the `class="yj-tapf-textarea"` in a variable and search for the input you want in that variable?

Comment: No. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: in python : `myclass = browser.find_element_by_class('yj-tapf-textarea')`
`myclass.find('input')` this will return a list, you can then iterate over that list until you find the one you want (iterate as a test, delete the iteration when you know which input you need ). Hope i make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I wasn't paying close enough attention to the classes and their locations. Here's what I ended up with:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("yj-auto-width-fake-textarea")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("yj-tapf-textarea")).sendKeys(Text);
driver.findElement(By.id("yj-yam.ui.publisher.old.SubmitButton")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id changes then perhaps it is a hint to not use id as the locator.

Using CssSelectors and XPath can give you more stable and reliable locators